# Realm １対多　構造でのNSData取得について

Tags: swift, ios, realm

Realmの1対多構造を作成し、レコードにユーザのオブジェクトIDと関連づいた辞書型配列をNSDataに変換したものを保存しております。ただ、関連づいたNSDataを取得、NSDataをアンアーカイブする方法がわかりません。

```
class UserClass: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var user: String = ""
    let colorData = List<Color>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "user"
    }
}

class VariousColor: Object {
    dynamic var colorData = NSData()
    let chidLink = LinkingObjects(fromType: UserClass.self, property: "colorData")
}
```

以下表示ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            let usrClass = UserClass()
            usrClass.user = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!
            let varColor = VariousColor()
            varColor.colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.colorDictionary)
            usrClass.colorData.append(varColor)
            realm.add(usrClass, update: true)
            print(varColor.colorData)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 現在、どのようにそれを実現しているのか、モデル定義やNSDataへ変換している部分のコードを載せてもらえますか？おそらくNSKeyedArchiverでNSDataにしてると思いますので、逆はNSKeyedUnarchiverを使うといいと思いますが、実際のコードがわからないとそれで合ってるかわかりません。また、NSDataにしてしまうと、それに対して検索したり並べ替えたりができなくなるので、あまりお勧めの方法ではありません。もっと良いやり方が提案できる場合がありますので、そのためにも現状のコードを見せてください。

Comment: コードの方記載させていただきました。idとuser、NSData用のカラムがそれぞれあるイメージです。NSDataには[NSIndexPath:UIColor]をアーカイブしてRealmに格納しております。何卒ご指導願います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

例えば保存したオブジェクトの取得と、NSDataから元のディクショナリを復元する処理は下記のようになります。

```
if let user = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(UserClass.self, key: "...") {
    for color in user.colorData {
        let colorDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(color.colorData)
        print(colorDictionary)
    }
}
```

ここではプライマリキーを使って保存したオブジェクトを取得しています。

```
realm.objectForPrimaryKey(UserClass.self, key: "...")
```

任意の検索条件でオブジェクトを取得するには以下のようにします。

```
realm.objects(UserClass.self).filter("user = %@", "...")
```

あとは通常のオブジェクトを使うのと同様で、この例ではオプショナルをアンラップし、`user.colorData`を１件ずつループして、それぞれを元のディクショナリに復元しています。

```
let colorDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(color.colorData)
```

復元の処理は^です。

Comment: 大変参考になりました。ありがとうございます。